# Get different alert box on each iframe click

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, three.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>three.js css3d - youtube</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    #blocker {
      /* background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5); */
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js"></script>

  <div id="container"></div>
  <div id="blocker"></div>

  <script>
    var camera, scene, renderer, glrenderer, glscene;

    function createGlRenderer() {
      var container = document.getElementById('container');
      glrenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: false
      });
      glrenderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
      glrenderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
      glrenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      glrenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
      glrenderer.domElement.style.top = 0;
      container.appendChild(glrenderer.domElement);
      return glrenderer;
    }

    function createCssrenderer() {
      var container = document.getElementById('container');
      var renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
      // renderer.domElement.style.zIndex = 1;
      renderer.domElement.style.top = 0;
      container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
      return renderer;
    }

    function createPlane(w, h, position, rotation) {
      var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x000000,
        opacity: 0.0,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide
      });
      var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(w, h);
      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      mesh.position.x = position.x;
      mesh.position.y = position.y;
      mesh.position.z = position.z;
      mesh.rotation.x = rotation.x;
      mesh.rotation.y = rotation.y;
      mesh.rotation.z = rotation.z;
      return mesh;
    }


    var Element = function(id, w, h, position, rotation, myfunc) {
      var html = [
        '<div id="blocker" style="width:' + w + 'px; height:' + h + 'px;">',
        '<iframe src="' + id + '" width="' + w + '" height="' + h + '" onclick="' + myfunc + '">',
        '</iframe>',
        '</div>'
      ].join('\n');
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      $(div).html(html);
      div.style.width = w;
      div.style.height = h;
      //div.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
      var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject(div);
      object.position.x = position.x;
      object.position.y = position.y;
      object.position.z = position.z;
      object.rotation.x = rotation.x;
      object.rotation.y = rotation.y;
      object.rotation.z = rotation.z;
      return object;
      var plane = createPlane(
        w, h,
        position,
        rotation);
      glscene.add(plane);
    }

    function myfunctiona() {
      alert("I am an alert box!");
    }


    init();
    animate();

    function init() {

      glscene = new THREE.Scene();
      glrenderer = createGlRenderer();
      scene = new THREE.Scene();
      renderer = createCssrenderer();
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
      camera.position.set(0, 100, 3000);
      var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1);
      glscene.add(ambientLight);
      var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
      directionalLight.position.set(-.5, .5, -1.5).normalize();
      glscene.add(directionalLight);

      var group = new THREE.Group();
      group.add(new Element('http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile', 1000, 1000, new THREE.Vector3(-1000, 0, 100), new THREE.Vector3(0, -50 * Math.PI / 180, 0), myfunctiona()));
      group.add(new Element('http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile', 900, 1000, new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 500), new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0)));
      group.add(new Element('http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile', 1000, 1000, new THREE.Vector3(1000, 0, 100), new THREE.Vector3(0, 50 * Math.PI / 180, 0)));
      scene.add(group);
      controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
      controls.rotateSpeed = 4;
      window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
      // Block iframe events when dragging camera
      var blocker = document.getElementById('blocker');
      blocker.style.display = 'none';
      document.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
        blocker.style.display = '';
      });
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        blocker.style.display = 'none';
      });
    }



    function onWindowResize() {
      camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      glrenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }

    function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      controls.update();
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      glrenderer.render(glscene, camera);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      initialize();

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am firing a javascript function whenever an iframe is clicked. But that javascript alert is loading with page itself and not when iframe is clicked. Iframe is embedded on three.js scene. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Can't register a click listener on an iframe element. An iframe has it's own window and any events occur inside that window

Comment: so is there any alternative for that

Comment: is there any option by any means that i can click that whole iframe to dislplay a pop up @charlietfl

Comment: Are the iframes from same domain as page is on?

Comment: Yes the iframes are of same domain as page is on @charlietfl